# how to SELECT a column which has a space in between its name

Tags: sql, oracle, occi

I am trying to execute  a SQL query through OCCI calls in my CPP program. 
I want to read 2 columns out of those one column name has a space in between. I tried enclosing the column name between `' '`, `" "`, `[ ]` and nothing helped. Can experts suggest me on answering this.

Below is my code:
....

```
string sqlStmt = "SELECT 'REJECTED COST', APPROVED_COST FROM COST_TABLE where PART_NUM= 'PN4879-1'";
stmt = conn->createStatement(sqlStmt);
ResultSet *rset = stmt->executeQuery();
double dRejCost = 0;
double dAppCost = 0;
if(rset->next())
        {
            dRejCost = rset->getNumber(1);
            dAppCost = rset->getNumber(2);

        }
stmt->closeResultSet(rset);
conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
```

Error/Exception:

> The error I get @ dRejCost = rset->getNumber(1);: 
>   ORA-01722: invalid number

PS: The ORACLE table has the many columns where "REJECTED COST" column header is named with a space. I don't have the privilege to ask the DB team to change the DB table name though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SQL standard requires such an identifier to be enclosed in double quotes: `"REJECTED COST"` and so does Oracle. Your code needs to use: `string sqlStmt = "SELECT \"REJECTED COST\", .... ";` (or whatever escapes C is using inside strings). Single quotes are only for string literals in SQL statements. But "*ORA-01722: invalid number*" stems from the fact that your current statement returns a string `'..'` for that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote character literals. I.e., you're selecting the string `'REJECTED COST'`, which, obviously, cannot be cast to a number.
In order to select a column name with a space, you should use double quotes (`"`). Note that they need to be escaped, as you're using them inside a c++ string, which is also denoted by double quotes:

```
string sqlStmt = "SELECT \"REJECTED COST\", APPROVED_COST FROM COST_TABLE where PART_NUM= 'PN4879-1'";
```